# Custom field, add class to anchor tag

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to add a class to an anchor tag within a custom field. Like:

```
<div class="custom-field-class"><a href="http://someurl.com" class="some-class">Awesome</a></div>
```

Thoughts on how to get `some-class` in place?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can add a class to an anchor tag like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.custom-field-class').children('a').addClass('some-class');
})
</script>
```